# URL escaping rules

Tags: url, escaping

How could it be, that this URL

`http://www.centuryparkcapital.com/news/century-park-portfolio-company-r%E2%80%A2o%E2%80%A2m-completes-its-fourth-acquisition`

is represented in my browser as

`http://www.centuryparkcapital.com/news/century-park-portfolio-company-r•o•m-completes-its-fourth-acquisition`?

Can't understand why sequence `%E2%80%A2` is turned into a single symbol `•`

Comment: Because it's UTF-8 encoded: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128

Comment: How to get the idea is that an UTF or just plain ASCII? The unescaping code I saw just analyze `%XX` sequence and turn it into a plain ASCII char through parsing integer with radix 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has something to do with UTF-8.

http://www.tachyonsoft.com/uc0020.htm#U2022